Coding an RSI-like indicator
I am creating an MT4 indicator that will look a little like the RSI indicator. I have the basic functionality working. In very simple terms my indicator is plotting the difference between 2 Moving Averages. The result should plot a line (in a separate window) on a scale of 0 to 100. The difference between the 2 Moving Averages could be positive or negative, small or large. I want any negative values to be plotted as 0 to 50, and positive values as 50 to 100. There will be 2 indicator levels (values to be determined, but maybe 40 and 60) as in the RSI.
The RSI.mq4 uses the following to achieve this (I think):
  if(ExtNegBuffer[InpRSIPeriod]!=0.0) {
     ExtRSIBuffer[InpRSIPeriod]=100.0-(100.0/(1.0+ExtPosBuffer[InpRSIPeriod]/ExtNegBuffer[InpRSIPeriod]));
  } else {
     if(ExtPosBuffer[InpRSIPeriod]!=0.0) {
        ExtRSIBuffer[InpRSIPeriod]=100.0;
     } else {
        ExtRSIBuffer[InpRSIPeriod]=50.0;
     }
  }

I don't really understand this code, particulary as it has positive and negative buffers, which I don't have. My (inadequate) code is as follows:
// Get the difference between the 2 MA buffers
ExtDiffBuffer[i] = ExtFastMABuffer[i] - ExtSlowMABuffer[i];

How can I expand on this to get the similar effect as the RSI? That is to say, ranging from about 0 to about 100.
Any help much appreciated. Regards, StuartM
